# Are these families the clopen sets of some class of topologies?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, set-partition

What would one call a family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets $X$ such that:

$$(1):X\in\mathcal{F}$$
$$(2):A,B\in\mathcal{F}\implies A\setminus B\in\mathcal{F}$$
$$(3):P\subseteq\mathcal{F}\text{ is a partition of }X\implies \forall Q\subseteq P(\cup_{S\in Q}S\in\mathcal{F})$$

Properties one and two are equivalently to saying the pair $(X,\mathcal{F})$ is a [field of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) however the third property is distinct. Do these have a name? They are coming up when I try to extend the notion of a "connected space" to [interior algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_algebra#Generalized_topology).

Note $\mathcal{L}=(\mathcal{F},\subseteq,\cup,\cap)$ is a distributive lattice since finite unions/intersections are closed in $\mathcal{F}$ in fact the join irreducibles of $\mathcal{L}$ are the atoms of $\mathcal{L}$, thus $\mathcal{L}$ is atomistic iff every element of $X$ belongs to an inclusion minimal set in $\mathcal{F}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ iff the sets in $\mathcal{F}$ are closed under arbitrary unions iff $(X,\mathcal{F})$ is a [partition topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_topology). What about if $(X,\mathcal{F})$ is not a partition topology?

Can these be characterized as the clopen sets of a particular class of topologies? If so, which ones?